# How to find the numbers NOT currently listed in /etc/services?

Tags: linux

Current employment only lists currently used Ports in /etc/services.  So it's hard to tell where others left off.  How can I find, what Port numbers are not listed there?

Comment: mmm, I don't see why the question has to do with python or perl

Comment: Why was this question upvoted?

Comment: @ikegami: [IANA port assignments](http://www.iana.org/assignments/port-numbers)

Answer (score 3):

Do you mean ports of programs actually running on your computer?  You may be able to use netstat or lsof to find these.

Or are you simply looking for common ports that your particular /etc/services may be missing?  Wikipedia has a list at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers if you wish to augment yours.

Comment: I'm looking for a simple script that will list the numbers NOT found in /etc/services.

Comment: The ones already listed there are taken and currently in use, so someone actually has to find which ones are NOT in use but it's hard to tell where the last person left off...